# Variation on thread locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I'm writing a web-scraping program which runs multiple requests at once. Some requests need to happen consecutively, though, so my first thought is to throw a lock around the two requests which need to happen together and a lock around the other requests. The problem with this approach is that the other two requests will lock on each other but are able to be run in parallel.

For example, I there are four pages I need data from on the website:

- example.com/page1
- example.com/page2
- example.com/page3
- example.com/page4

When the program starts, I kick off three threads: one for page1, one for page2 and page 3, and one for page4. The request for page3 MUST happen DIRECTLY after the request for page2. The requests for page1 and page4 can happen simultaneously.

If I don't using locking, page1 or page4 may be requested in between the requests for page2 and page3 and cause problems. If I use the same lock for the the three threads, then the request to page1 may block requests to page4.

What can I do to prevent a request from happening between page2 and page3, but allow other requests to happen simultaneously?

Comment: Obligatory warning: If you care so much about the order in which stuff runs, threading may be the wrong answer.  You're trying to nominally run stuff in parallel, but then force it to run serially -- which defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: "The request for page2 MUST happen after the request for page2." - currently this typo (whatever it is) makes the question very hard to understand.

Comment: @cHao, depending on what job is, it may we an advantage to create and start threads, so they can, to example, do some initialization and then just wait for trigger. This could be especially time saving, if preparing data for threads and creating threads run in parallel.

Comment: @cHao, I care about the order of some of the requests, but not the requests as a whole.

Comment: @JonSkeet, Sorry, fixed it.

Comment: Why not simply do page 2 and 3 on the same thread then, in the right order?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I've been awake too long. The request for page3 needs to happen DIRECTLY after the request for page2. No requests can happen in between.

Comment: Can other pages be retrieved while page 2 or 3 is being retrieved? I think you need to outline **specifically** how you want these pages to be retrieved because I sure don't understand exactly what you mean here.

Comment: I'm guessing that a thread that handles a '2+3' request must wait until any '1,4' request/s currently in progress have completed, then execute completely before any further '1,4' requests can be made.  It is a little unclear:)

Answer (score 1):

You might try using a semaphore to control access to the 'page request' pseudo-resource. Requests that can run concurrently require only a single resource, requests that must run exclusively require all the resources.

Something like the following:

```
private static Semaphore _pool;
private static readonly int kMaxConcurrrentPageRequesters = 4;  // or whatever number

// at some appropriate initialization point

_pool = new Semaphore(kMaxConcurrrentPageRequesters,kMaxConcurrrentPageRequesters);


// when a normal request is being made that can run concurrently:

_pool.WaitOne();
perform_page_request();
_pool.Release();


// when an exclusive page request is being made:

// maybe create a Semaphore wrapper that stores the max semaphore count
//   so that you can expose a `WaitAll()` method to replace this loop
for (int i = 0; i < kMaxConcurrrentPageRequesters; ++i) {
    _pool.WaitOne();
}
perform_exclusive_page_requests();
_pool.Release(kMaxConcurrrentPageRequesters);
```

Comment: Could maybe deadlock if more than one thread attempts an exclusive_page_request at the same time, but maybe this is not an issue.

Comment: @MartinJames: good point - for the moment at least, I'll leave a solution to that for the reader. I suspect the solution might not be trivial. So for now this answer is only safe if there's only a single thread that might want exclusive access.

Answer (score 0):

You could delay execution of threads or make them waiting. To example,

```
var waitA = false;
var thread1 = new Thread((Action)(() => { while(!waitA) Thread.Sleep(0); /* do work here */ })).Start();
var thread2 = new Thread((Action)(() => { while(!waitA) Thread.Sleep(0); /* do work here */ })).Start();
// prepare data for threads? and start them
waitA = true;
```